# How to horizontally flip a rotoscoped object?

Tags: edit-mode

I'm very new to blender so please don't flame me.

I recently recorded a show on zoom about technology. Here's the problem, during the zoom meeting, my background that had a logo called 'DNA' which is normal, but after the show, when I saved the video and watched it again, it showed my background logo as 'AND'(which is DNA flipped). That's why I'm in blender trying to isolate(rotoscope) the logo('AND') and flip it horizontally to ('DNA').

Here's the logo and how it should look like:

[image: DNA]

I really appreciate it if anyone knows how to fix this thanks.

Comment: Hello :). So, are you asking how to flip video in Blender horizontally?

Comment: and isolating the logo...i think ;)

Comment: Can you add a screen capture of 1 frame showing the messed up logo?  How to solve this depends on a lot of things, including whether or not the logo is ever obscured.  Also, I don't think Blender is the best tool for what you want to do.